# jQuery make the height for another two li as the same height like the tallest

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kpatel/7sHe7/). In this you can see my markup is just like bunch of li inside ul. In this I have made 3 lis as one row and another next 3 lis as another row and so on. Now I have used jQuery to take the height of one li which height is the more then the other 2 lis and make the 2 lis into the same height of tallest li. Here my jQuery is working fine for the first row but it is not working for other rows. So can someone tell me how to make the same height to execute for other rows? Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.
My jQuery code is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(function() {
      var items = $("ul.products li");
      var rows = items.length / 3;
      if (rows <= 0)
        rows = 1;
      for(var r=0;r<rows;r++) {
        normalizeRowHeight(r, items);

      }
    });

    function normalizeRowHeight(row, itemSet) {
      var maxRowHeight = 0;
      itemSet.slice(0,3).each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).height() > maxRowHeight )
          maxRowHeight = $(this).height();
        });  
      itemSet.slice(0,3).each(function(i) {
        $(this).css('height', maxRowHeight + "px");
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: why can't you just do this using css??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the numbers within your `.slice()` for each row so, `.slice(0, 3)` becomes `.slice(3, 6)` and then `.slice(6, 9)` and so on. Something like the following would do the trick:

```
(function($) {
  function normalizeHeight(items) {
    var maxHeight = 0, itemHeight;

    items.each(function() {
      itemHeight = $(this).height();
      if (itemHeight > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = itemHeight;
      }
    }).height(maxHeight + 'px');
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var itemsPerRow = 3,
        items = $('ul.products li'),
        rows = items.length / itemsPerRow, 
        r, min, max;

    if (rows < 1) rows = 1;

    for(r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
      min = itemsPerRow * r,
      max = min + itemsPerRow;
      normalizeHeight(items.slice(min, max));
    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

I've put a [demo on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/igibem/7/edit).

Comment: thanks ..Your trick worked fine but can you explain me about your codes.. Sorry to ask you as I am newbie to jQuery..Curious to know how the magic happened?

Comment: This is practically the same as what you did except you had hardcoded .slice(0, 3) which meant it would only apply normalizeRow to the first three `<li>`'s... In order to apply it to each row, you need to iterate through the rows so you can update that .slice() each time. Does that make sense? I'm not that great at explaining things sorry ha.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hole in your logic to select which slice you are operating on. You always work on the first 3 items.

Try this:

```
function normalizeRowHeight(row, itemSet) {
  var maxRowHeight = 0;
  itemSet.slice(row * 3,(row + 1)*3).each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).height() > maxRowHeight )
      maxRowHeight = $(this).height();
    });  
  itemSet.slice(row * 3,(row + 1)*3).each(function(i) {
    $(this).css('height', maxRowHeight + "px");
  });
}
```

Comment: @thanks Rob White thanks for the answer that worked perfectly. But can you describe me what is going here in that line where you have made changes. Curious to here from you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            var i=0,j=0;
            $('li').each(function(){
                j=$(this).height();
                if (i<j)
                    i=j;
            });
            $('li').each(function(){
                $(this).height(i);//set Max height of li to other li
                alert($(this).height());
            });
        });
```

[See working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/pLmLv/)